# What does using right/left/up/down key and option/command key together mean?

Tags: keyboard

Using right/left/up/down keys with Fn key can do the same as page down / page up / home / end on a PC.

Some mentioned about using right/left/up/down keys with either option or command key in http://www.apple.com/shop/question/answers/mac/how-can-i-make-the-home-and-end-keys-on-the-apple-extended-keyboard-work-as-line-commands-rather-than-page-commands/Q7HY7K2UFDTUK7J7C .
What do they mean under OS X?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>← or →</kbd> jumps to the left/right end of the current line
<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>↑ or ↓</kbd> jumps to the top/bottom of the current page
<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>← or →</kbd> jumps to the left/right adjacent word
<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>↑ or ↓</kbd> jumps to the start/end of the paragraph
*<sub>(all terms are respective)</sub>*

Comment: Thanks. Do they only apply to microsoft office software, or to OS X, or to most software on OS X?

Comment: @Tim they should apply globally throughout OS X. Let me check though

Comment: @Tim they do apply throughout OS X, Microsoft Office, Pages, Numbers, TextEdit... Most if not all OS X applications support these shortcuts.

Comment: ...and just for completeness, Fn+arrow keys work as pg up/pg down/home/end for up/down/left/right respectively